# jQuery Image Slider - controls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need help. I have a simple jQuery slider, and it works perfectly, but I can't figure out this situation: For example, if I have 4 images, and when I reach the fourth image, I want to be able to go from the fourth to the first image by clicking the 'next' button. How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').on('click', function(){
        var currentImg = $('.active');
        var nextImg = currentImg.next();

        if(nextImg.length){
            currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
            nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
        }
    });

    $('.prev').on('click', function(){
        var currentImg = $('.active');
        var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

        if(prevImg.length){
            currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
            prevImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.controls{
    display: flex;
}
.control{
    padding:20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border:1px solid #939393;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: 'Recife';
    user-select: none;
}
.prev{
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #939393;
}
.img-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.img-wrapper img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: none;
}
.img-wrapper img.active{
    display: inline-block;
}
.next{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
            <span class="prev control">prev</span>
            <span class="next control">next</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="img-one.jpg" alt="one" class="active">
            <img src="img-two.jpg" alt="two">
            <img src="img-three.jpg" alt="three">
            <img src="img-four.jpg" alt="four">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when next is clicked it checks if there's an image after current image. If that's not the case it won't do anything. But you can add an else statement to return to the first item when there's no next element.

Change following code.

```
if(nextImg.length){
    currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
    nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
}
```

to

```
currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
if(nextImg.length){
    nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
} else {
    var first = $('.img-wrapper img:first-child');
    first.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
}
```

This code will remove `.active` class from current image when you click next and add it either to first element or next element.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want same for prev button, you do the same, but this time you choose the last-child instead of first-child.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thank you so much!